# Multiple associations from single table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In an attempt to expand on [this guide](http://www.spacevatican.org/2008/5/6/creating-multiple-associations-with-the-same-table/) for creating multiple associations with the same table I came up with the following user class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password

    validates_uniqueness_of :email
    validates_presence_of :email
    validates_presence_of :name
    belongs_to :role
    has_many :clients, foreign_key: 'rep_id'
    has_many :submitted_jobs, class_name: 'WorkOrder', through: :clients
    has_many :processing_tasks, class_name: 'WorkOrder', foreign_key: 'processor_id'

    def has_role?(role_sym)
        role.name.underscore.to_sym == role_sym 
    end
end
```

My goal is to be able to refer to submitted jobs and processing tasks separately depending on the type of user. So far the processing tasks part works as I expected and so far I can get the rep from the workorder, but when I attempt something like rep.submitted_jobs I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5@rails4/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/reflection.rb:100:in `_reflect_on_association' 
ect...
```

Clearly the has_many through relationship works differently than I'm expecting, but I'm not even quite sure what to call this type of relationship so I'm at something of a loss for what to look for.
Its probably also worth noting that

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  it {should validate_uniqueness_of(:email)}
  it {should validate_presence_of(:name)}
  it {should belong_to(:role)}
  it {should have_many(:submitted_jobs)}
  it {should have_many(:processing_tasks)}
end
```

all pass

EDIT:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
  has_many :addresses, through: :contacts
  has_many :permits
  has_many :work_orders
  validates :clientnumber, format: { with: /\A\d{3}\z/ },
                                    length: { is: 3 }

  belongs_to :rep, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :default_processor, class_name: 'User'
end
```

EDIT 2:
work order associations

```
class WorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :project_type
  belongs_to :status
  belongs_to :labels
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :processor, class_name: 'User'
  has_one :rep, through: :client, class_name: 'User'
  has_one :presort_information
  has_one :printing_instructions
  has_one :production_details
  ........
end
```

Comment: what does the Client model look like?

Comment: Updated the question with it

Comment: Can you show your `WorkOrder` model assocations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical has_many_through_association look like

[image]

To solve this problem, you could write custom association, a method that will give you related work_orders

Inside User model

```
def submitted_jobs
  WorkOrder.joins(:client).where('clients.rep_id = ?', self.id)
end
```

Comment: Does using the built in rails associations provide any additional advantages? Because I like the idea of just using a method for things they I may want some granular control over the return (for example the processing tasks) and I had just assumed the associations somehow made the database "work", or was I totally off base?